# Constraints on marginal distribution given joint distribution definition

Tags: joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

I am trying to understand a part of the paper ['From optimal transport to generative modelling: the VEGAN cookbook'](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07642) by Bousquet, Gelly, Tolstikhin, Simon-Gabriel and Schölkopf. There is a one-liner in this paper that I am struggling to understand. For self-containedness I will state the problem here:

Consider the set of all joint distributions over three random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ that satisfies the following properties (denote this set as $\mathcal{P}_{(X, Y, Z)}$):

The marginals $P_X$, $P_{(Y, Z)}$ and $P_Z$ are all prescribed, and in addition $(X \perp\!\!\!\perp Y) | Z$. Denote by $\mathcal{P}_{(X, Y)}$ the set of marginals on $(X, Y)$ induced by distributions in $\mathcal{P}_{(X, Y, Z)}$.

Now let $\mathcal{P}(X \sim P_X, Y \sim P_Y)$ be the set of all joint distributions over $X$ and $Y$ with marginals $P_X$ and $P_Y$.

The paper states that from these definitions it is clear that $\mathcal{P}_{(X, Y)} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X \sim P_X, Y \sim P_Y)$. My question is, why is this not an equality? How do the conditions above imply that it is a subset? Given the assertion is true, is it always a strict subset?

Any help greatly appreciated!